# Executing new URL string on click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and want to pass it to the browsers URL on click (it works fine in the console):

Javascript:

```
$('a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var test  = removeURLParameter(url, 'pageurl');
    console.log(test)

    function removeURLParameter(url, parameter) {
        //prefer to use l.search if you have a location/link object
        var urlparts= url.split('?');   
        if (urlparts.length>=2) {

            var prefix= encodeURIComponent(parameter)+'=';
            var pars= urlparts[1].split(/[&;]/g);

            //reverse iteration as may be destructive
            for (var i= pars.length; i-- > 0;) {    
                //idiom for string.startsWith
                if (pars[i].lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== -1) {  
                    pars.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }

            url= urlparts[0]+'?'+pars.join('&');
            return url;
        } else {
            return url;
        }
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is remove &pageurl=NUMERIC VALUE from the URL and execute it in the browsers URL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your `test` URL is correct, then it's just a matter of doing:

```
window.location.href = test;
```

And to prevent the default event handler from being fired, add:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Also `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Thanks, but I have another issue now, the code removes #tab_c from the URL e.g. example.com/?test=1&pageurl=10#tab_c... It removes pageurl but I'd like to keep the # value, any ideas @Barmar

Comment: @user3742990 Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location You need to just process `window.location.search`, and then put the URL back together with `window.location.hash`.

Comment: I'm new to Javascript, not sure how to do this.. @Barmar